# Vertical scrollbar on iframe not updating as iframe loads new pages

Tags: html, css, iframe

Here is my iframe code:

```
<iframe style="margin:0 auto; display:block;" width="960" height="1500" src="http://www.test.com"></iframe>
```

The problem I have is as follows. The initial page load of the iframe is a page which is not very tall. But as the user navigates through different pages on the iframe, the heights of these pages differ (sometimes as high as 7500px). The problem is the vertical scrollbar does not update to reflect the change in page size.

The vertical scrollbar remains the same proportion as it was on the initial page load.

So on a tall page when I scroll the vertical scrollbar down to the bottom of the iframe it doesn't reach the bottom of the page, if that makes sense.

How can I make the iframe vertical scrollbar auto update on each page load within the iframe?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the CSS of the page you load in the `iframe`. Can you show some of the CSS? Probably from the `body`?

Comment: do you want to change the height of the iframe ?

Comment: @putvande I agree. I have done some testing on an iframe content whose height randomly changes on a button reload and the iframe vertical scrollbar adjusts accordingly. Can you give me any clues how to debug the css? As I see no errors. I am using bootstrap 3 with some additional style sheets. The site structure is rather complicated. I am bound not to post anything directly since this is for my job. But I will try to recreate a toy example that replicates the issue. Thank you for your assistance.